# how to show only since and until date data

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the next sql code

```
SELECT date,count(clics)
FROM advertising_clics
WHERE date > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
GROUP BY date
```

The Result is

```
date            count(clics)
2015-08-29          4
2015-08-30          1
2015-08-31          1
2015-09-01          1
2015-09-02          1
```

but I want the result to be this

```
date            count(clics)
    2015-08-29          4
    2015-09-02          1
```

Comment: `union` the counts for the two days you want (`CURDATE()` and `CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY`).

Comment: So use a `where` clause ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try getting first record and last record  and `union` both the results as

```
SELECT date,count(clics)
FROM advertising_clics
WHERE date > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
GROUP BY date
order by date
limit 1

union

SELECT date,count(clics)
FROM advertising_clics
WHERE date > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
GROUP BY date
order by date desc
limit 1
```